# No such host is known- QnA Maker

Tags: botframework

I am using a `dispatch` model with 2 `LUIS` model and 1 `QnA` maker. On emulator everything works but after publishing, when I debug it on `Web Chat` channel on `Azure` or on `Teams` my `QnA` Maker utterances always returns

```
No such host is known.
```

I have tried using both the host names one from the settings page in QnA maker portal and `westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/Qnamaker`

Can someone help.

Comment: Have you checked your LUIS host names? https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/qnamaker-support/csharp_dotnetcore

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found out the reason it wasn't just `QnA Maker` but also `LUIS` , I have to update the `LuisAPIHostName` in the `appsettings.json` from `westus` to `westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com`and update `LUIS Host Name` as  `$"https://{configuration["LuisAPIHostName"]}")` in `BotServices`

And off course has to publish it again.